# Why isn't my profile setting working with multithreading in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, firefox, selenium, watir

I need PDFs on my browser to automatically save instead of being displayed.  I wrote a POC program to test this, and it works.  The code is:

```
$profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new

$profile['browser.download.folderlist'] = 2
$profile['browser.download.dir'] = "\home\automation\\"
$profile['pdfjs.disabled'] = true
$profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "application/pdf"
$profile['browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force'] = false
$profile['browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting'] = false

$browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => $profile
```

The PDFs save into the folder I want without being displayed, and all is good.

However, when I port the code to work with my actual multi-threading code like this:

```
Thread.current["testDir"] = $mainDirectory + "/" + thisCase.testCaseID + "/"
Thread.current["profile"]  = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
Thread.current["profile"]['browser.download.folderList'] = 2
Thread.current["profile"]['browser.download.dir'] = Thread.current["testDir"]
Thread.current["profile"]['pdfjs.disabled'] = true
Thread.current["profile"]['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "application/pdf"
Thread.current["profile"]['browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force'] = false
Thread.current["profile"]['browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting'] = false  

Thread.current["tBrowser"] = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => Thread.current["profile"]
```

the PDF gets displayed and does not save.  What gives?  How can I make this work correctly?